# is there a way to have the terminal print out the last recorded value of a variable?

Tags: java, terminal

I have the following code. I am typing in the terminal 'javac Hwk2014.java' followed by 'java Hwk2014 1 2 + ' and this should give me an output of 3. When I do it with a newly generated array 'args2', I do get 3. When I type in the arguments with a for loop, it clearly says args[0] is 1 and so forth.  So its all there, but the output keeps being '0'

code:

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Hwk2014 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hi");
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Argument " + i + ": " + args[i]);
        }
        String[] args2 = new String[3];
        args2[0] = "1";
        args2[1] = "2";
        args2[2] = "+";
        /*args2[3] = "3";
        args2[4] = "*";*/
        //System.out.println("+args[0]");
        String value1, value2;
        int addValue = 0, multiplyValue = 0, lastValue = 0;
        //int j = 0, h = 0;
        String addValueS, multiplyValueS;
        Stack<String> object = new Stack<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
        {
            object.push(args[i]);
            if (object.size() >= 2 && object.peek() == "+")
            {
                object.pop();
                value1 = object.pop();
                value2 = object.pop();
                addValue = Integer.parseInt(value1) + Integer.parseInt(value2);
                addValueS = Integer.toString(addValue);
                object.push(addValueS);
                if (i == (args.length - 1))
                {
                    lastValue = addValue;
                }
            }
            if (object.size() >= 2 && object.peek() == "*")
            {
                object.pop();
                value1 = object.pop();
                value2 = object.pop();
                multiplyValue = Integer.parseInt(value1) * Integer.parseInt(value2);
                multiplyValueS = Integer.toString(multiplyValue);
                object.push(multiplyValueS);
                if (i == (args.length - 1))
                {
                    lastValue = multiplyValue;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(lastValue);
    }
}
```

Test:

```
Input: ~%java Hwk2014 1 2 + 

output: 0
```

Comment: print out the array args. System.out.println(Arrays.toString(args));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### TL;DR

The below is my interpretation of your question but I may have misinterpreted it. You may simply be trying to write code to [Evaluate the Value of an Arithmetic Expression in Reverse Polish Notation in Java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/evaluate-the-value-of-an-arithmetic-expression-in-reverse-polish-notation-in-java/)

### My Answer

The below code does not check that the [java] command-line arguments are valid. It assumes that the arguments are repeats of

```
number number operator
```

where *operator* is one of the following:

- `+` for addition
- `/` for division
- `*` for multiplication
- `-` for subtraction

Note that because of the way that the operator characters are interpreted on the command line, you may need to delimit them. (See example after below code.)

```java
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Stack;

public class Hwk2014 {
    enum Operator {
        ADD, DIVIDE, MULTIPLY, SUBTRACT;

        public String toString() {
            switch (this) {
                case ADD:
                    return "\uFF0B";
                case DIVIDE:
                    return "\u00F7";
                case MULTIPLY:
                    return "\u00D7";
                case SUBTRACT:
                    return "\u2212";
                default:
                    return this.toString();
            }
        }
    }

    private static int add(int operand1, int operand2) {
        return operand1 + operand2;
    }

    private static void calculate(Operator operator, int operand1, int operand2) {
        double result = Double.MIN_VALUE;
        switch (operator) {
            case ADD:
                result = add(operand1, operand2);
                break;
            case DIVIDE:
                result = divide(operand1, operand2);
                break;
            case MULTIPLY:
                result = multiply(operand1, operand2);
                break;
            case SUBTRACT:
                result = subtract(operand1, operand2);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Unhandled operator: " + operator);
        }
        System.out.printf("%d %s %d = %f%n", operand1, operator, operand2, result);
    }

    private static double divide(int operand1, int operand2) {
        return operand1 / (double) operand2;
    }

    private static double multiply(int operand1, int operand2) {
        return operand1 * operand2 * 1.0d;
    }

    private static int subtract(int operand1, int operand2) {
        return operand1 - operand2;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Operator> map = Map.of("+", Operator.ADD,
                                           "/", Operator.DIVIDE,
                                           "*", Operator.MULTIPLY,
                                           "-", Operator.SUBTRACT);
        Stack<String> stack = new Stack<>();
        for (String arg : args) {
            stack.push(arg.replace("'", ""));
        }
        Operator operator = null;
        int operand1 = 0;
        int operand2 = 0;
        int remainder = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            String val = stack.pop();
            remainder = i % 3;
            switch (remainder) {
                case 0:
                    if (operator != null) {
                        calculate(operator, operand1, operand2);
                    }
                    operator = map.get(val);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    operand1 = Integer.parseInt(val);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    operand2 = Integer.parseInt(val);
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Problem? remainder = "  + remainder);
            }
        }
        if (remainder == 2  &&  operator != null) {
            calculate(operator, operand1, operand2);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a sample command (on Windows 10):

```
java Hwk2014 2 1 + 7 6 '*' 7 22 "/" 12 5 "-"
```

And here is the output:

```
5 − 12 = -7.000000
22 ÷ 7 = 3.142857
6 × 7 = 42.000000
1 ＋ 2 = 3.000000
```

Refer to [Enum Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)<sup>+</sup>
Refer to [The Map Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html)<sup>+</sup>
Refer to [Characters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html)<sup>+</sup>
Refer to [Formatting Numeric Print Output](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html)<sup>+</sup>

<sup>+</sup>Part of [Oracle's Java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html)

### Your Code

There are two problems in your code. Here is your corrected code with explanations of the problems after the code. I changed two lines, both of which are marked with the comment *CHANGES HERE*

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Hwk2014 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hi");
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Argument " + i + ": " + args[i]);
        }
        String[] args2 = new String[3];
        args2[0] = "1";
        args2[1] = "2";
        args2[2] = "+";
        /*args2[3] = "3";
        args2[4] = "*";*/
        //System.out.println("+args[0]");
        String value1, value2;
        int addValue = 0, multiplyValue = 0, lastValue = 0;
        //int j = 0, h = 0;
        String addValueS, multiplyValueS;
        Stack<String> object = new Stack<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
        {
            object.push(args[i]);
            if (object.size() > 2 && "+".equals(object.peek())) // CHANGES HERE
            {
                object.pop();
                value1 = object.pop();
                value2 = object.pop();
                addValue = Integer.parseInt(value1) + Integer.parseInt(value2);
                addValueS = Integer.toString(addValue);
                object.push(addValueS);
                if (i == (args.length - 1))
                {
                    lastValue = addValue;
                }
            }
            if (object.size() > 2 && "*".equals(object.peek())) // CHANGES HERE 
            {
                object.pop();
                value1 = object.pop();
                value2 = object.pop();
                multiplyValue = Integer.parseInt(value1) * Integer.parseInt(value2);
                multiplyValueS = Integer.toString(multiplyValue);
                object.push(multiplyValueS);
                if (i == (args.length - 1))
                {
                    lastValue = multiplyValue;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(lastValue);
    }
}
```

The condition `object.size() >= 2` will be true when the `Stack` only contains two elements but you need it to contain three elements, hence I changed it to `object.size() > 2`. That is your first problem.

The second problem is that you are not correctly comparing strings. You need to use method `equals` and not the operator `==`. Refer to [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

When I run your corrected code, I get the following output:

```
Hi
Argument 0: 2
Argument 1: 1
Argument 2: +
3
```

Comment: why is there is a need for ' ' around * and " " around - or / ?   I tried java Hwk2014 1 2 + 3 *      and the output was:
 Argument 0: 1,
Argument 1: 2,
Argument 2: +,
Argument 3: 3,
Argument 4: Hwk2014.class,
Argument 5: Hwk2014.java,
Argument 6: Testing.java,
0

Comment: It works for / alone as well.  Only * requires ' ' around it. Wonder why

Comment: _Only * requires ' ' around it._ Because `*` is a special character for the command interpreter you are using. On Windows this is [CMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe) which replaces `*` with all the files in the working directory. Since I could not ascertain which operating system you are using, I wrote in my answer: _Note that because of the way that the operator characters are interpreted on the command line, you may need to delimit them_

Answer (score 0):

Your code is so complicated for something that simple.

```java
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        int value1 = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int value2 = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        String modifier = args[2];
        int result;
        
        switch(modifier) {
            case "+": result=(value1 + value2); break;
            case "-": result=(value1 - value2); break;
            case "*": result=(value1 * value2); break;
            default : result=(value1 / value2); break;
        }
        
        System.out.println("result: " + result);
    }
}
```

```
$ java Main 4 2 +
result: 6
$ java Main 4 2 -
result: 2
$ java Main 4 2 \*
result: 8
$ java Main 4 2 \/
result: 2
```

Comment: Your code only works for 2 numbers. The input can be more than that.  EX: 1 2 + 3 * 3 + 2